# If square matrix A satisfying $A^2-4A+4I=0$ does it follow that A is diagonizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples, diagonalization, characteristic-polynomial

I am given the following statement and asked to determine whether it is true or false:

> If $A$ is an $n\times n$-matrix, and $A^2-4A+4I=0$, then $A$ is diagonizable.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? If you show us what you've tried so far, people will feel much more inclined to help you out.

Comment: I agree with you, usually I do not just post a problem demanding an answer. However, I realized this problem was in fact beyond the curriculum which I was taught. At the time I had no idea of the methods used to determine the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The equation $A^2 -4A +4I =  0$ can be written as $(A -2I)^2 =0$ and hence $A-2I$ must be a nilpotent matrix of order $2$. Therefore the only eigenvalue of $A-2I$ is $0$ and so the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $2$. Now it is easy to see that $A$ and $A-2I$ have the same eigenvectors and therefore the dimension of their respective eigenspaces must be the same. It follows that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A-2I$ is diagonalizable. Since the only diagonalizable nilpotent matrix is the zero matrix we conclude that $A$ is not diagonalizable unless it equals $2I$.

Answer (score 3):

"Hint": Consider the matrix
$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\0&2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The minimum polynomial is
$$
m(\lambda)=\lambda^2-4\lambda+4=(\lambda-2)^2
$$
So the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $2$. Since the $m(\lambda)$ is not of linear factor, $A$ is not diagonizable. A Jordan block has a maximum size of $2$.

An example of $A$ is
$$
A=\pmatrix{2 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 2&0 \\ 0 &0 &2}
$$

Comment: I have never seen this "minimum polynomial" could you explain where it comes from?

Comment: "Since the $m(\lambda)$ is not linear...." What do you mean by *linear*, here?

Comment: That's not what 'linear' means.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to say that the minimal polynomial is not radical? That is, it is not a product of distinct linear factors...

Comment: No linear factor means that it only has simple root.

Comment: You are not told that the minimum polynomial is $\lambda^2-4\lambda+4$. The matrix $2I$ also obeys the equation.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not necessarily true that the minimal polynomial is $(\lambda - 2)^2$. For instance, if $A= 2\mathbf{I}$, where $\mathbf{I}$ is the unit matrix, then it clearly satisfies the equation, its minimal polynomial is $\lambda -2$ and it's, of course, diagonalizable. (Of course, it also satisfies the simpler equation $A - 2\mathbf{I} = 0$, but the problem doesn't preclude this possibility.)

Comment: yes, I know the minimal polynomial could be $(λ−2)$. But problem is true or false. So there is only one choice. Normally it is not diagonizable.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler answer is to calculate the minimal polynomial, which (by dropping exponents of all factors of the characteristic polynomial) : $\lambda-2$. So what we need to check is if ${\bf A}-2 {\bf I} = 0$ or not.